# How can I run `powershell` command on mcr.microsoft.com/powershell container

Tags: docker

My docker image is from `mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest` which has `powershell` installed. Why do I get this error when build docker image: `/bin/sh: 1: Install-Module: not found`

Below is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest
RUN Install-Module dbatools -Force
```

I can run the command `Install-Module dbatools -Force` when I manually launch a container from `mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest`. Why can't I run it from building the image? Does it have a different context? If it uses my localhost context, does it mean I need to install `powershell` on my Mac OS?

If I want to run a powershell script as ENTRYPOINT, how can I specify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `SHELL` directive in `Dockerfile`:

```
escape=`
SHELL ["powershell","-command"]
RUN New-Item -ItemType Directory C:\Example
```

see more [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell)

Comment: Is this command running on my local or inside docker container? I expect it is running on my local which mean I need to install powershell locally first right?